# Rails: find by day of week with timestamp

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to grab the records for same day of the week for the preceeding X days of the week. There must be a better way to do it than this:

Transaction.find_by_sql "select * from transactions where EXTRACT(DOW from date) = 1 and organisation_id = 4 order by date desc limit 7"

It gets me what I need but is Postgres specific and not very "Rails-y". Date is a timestamp.
Anyone got suggestions?

Comment: is the day dependent on users timezone or the server's?

Comment: The day would be the current day according to the server.

Comment: How many weeks back do you need to go?

Comment: I want 7 days in total. So if today is Wednesday, I need the previous 6 Wednesdays as well.

Answer (score 1):

How many days do you want to go back?

I have written a gem called [by_star](http://github.com/radar/by_star) that has a dynamic finder suited for finding up to a certain number of days in the past. If the number of days was always a number you could use this finder:

```
Transaction.as_of_3_days_ago
```

If it was dynamic then I would recommend using something such as `future` or `between`, depending on if you have transactions in the future (i.e. time travel):

```
Transaction.future(params[:start_date].to_time)
Transaction.between(params[:start_date].to_time, Time.now)
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Rails has no any methods to do this by other way. So best, and faster, solution - build DOW index on date column and use your query.